# Converting list(numpy_array) to list(list) and comparing 2 lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

```
List1 = ['SSA','NTSS','BB','KI']
List2 = [array(['(IEDSS)'],dtype=object), array(['PSG'], dtype=object), array(['KI'], dtype=object)],array(['IEDSS'], dtype=object)]
```

The questions are given below

1. I want to convert List 2 as list 1 i.e. converting list(numpy array) to list(list)

   Output should be `list2 = ['IEDSS','PSG','KI', 'IEDSS']`
2. Filter two list so that I get unique output from list 2 . For example

   ```
    final_list = ['IEDSS','PSG']
   ```

For question 2 asked above, I have tried using

```
def common_elements(list1, list2):
        result = []
        for element in list1:
                if element not in list2:
                    result.append(element)
        return result
```

But Iam not getting the required output.

Comment: "which need to be answered" what a enticing way to put it, especially without showing the slightest amount of effort... [ask]

Comment: sorry for the formation of question

Comment: Atleast try it with a for loop then if you want improvements then we can help

Comment: `[arr.tolist() for arr in list2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your arrays to lists, extract the first item and replace parentheses with whitespace. This is performed within a set comprehension to extract unique values.

Then use `set.difference`, or its syntactic sugar `-`, to remove items common with `List1`.

```
import numpy as np

List1 = ['SSA','NTSS','BB','KI']
List2 = [np.array(['(IEDSS)'], dtype=object), np.array(['PSG'], dtype=object),
         np.array(['KI'], dtype=object), np.array(['IEDSS'], dtype=object)]

Set2 = {i.tolist()[0].replace('(', '').replace(')', '') for i in List2}

res = list(Set2 - set(List1))

print(res)

['IEDSS', 'PSG']
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice...It worked

Comment: @Sheetal, Great. If this helped, please do [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green tick on left), so other users know.